# Google PageSpeed Insights Size content to viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to increase PageSpeed insights score, and I'm probably misunderstanding one part: Size content to viewport, recommendations show me that some html elements are outside of viewport, how do I fix it? I tried decreasing font sizes where text is really large but it doesn't help, is it only related with CSS?

Here's the results: https://goo.gl/PB2yaA

Comment: When going to the google Insights link, it tells me that some javascript and CSS links at the top of your code are slowing down your page. Even my browser has problems with it...
PageSpeed will remark this when it notices that your HTML code points to a blocking piece of JavaScript code.
I could explain the details to you, but the links on the PageSpeed page will tell you the same.
Solution: put the code that needs to be executed first inline. This way, your browser won't need to download the JS files and can just execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your Content at 361px - ~450px ist to big. Google is telling you, some Elements (like eg the .nav-toggle) are outside the viewport and not clickable.

Your Code:

```
(max-width: 480px) 
html, body {
width: 480px !important;
```

is not OK, because it forces the viewport to be bigger than the possible 440px viewport. Removing it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, it helped! I was scratching my head about this one for a while, it was easier than I thought, now I have three more elements to fix, could you inspect what changes are necessary to completely finish it? It seems I don't know where to look at.